# React router - get route prop outside of bound component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, prop

I defined some routes :

```
render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={IndexContainer} />
            <Route path="/agence" headerWhite={true} component={AgencyContainer} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

As you can see, I have a prop `headerWhite={true}` on `/agence` route. I can access it in my `AgencyContainer` component via `this.props.route.headerWhite`. But what I want is to be able to access it in my `App` component. Is there a simple way to do it ?

What I want to achieve is to pass that `headerWhite` prop to my `Header` component which is rendered in my `App` component because it has to be on every page of the website.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Read about contexts in React here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html. This should help

Comment: Thanks, I just read it. With this I can get an instance of the Router, but it seems there is nothing in the [RouterContext API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#contextrouter) that allows me to get the current route in order to get its props. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the following :

```
import React from 'react';
import Page from './Page';
import Header from './Header';

function getCurrentRoute(router, routes) {
    const currentRoute = routes.filter(route => route.path && router.isActive(route.path, true));

    return currentRoute[0];
}

function App(props, context) {
    const currentRoute = getCurrentRoute(context.router, props.routes);

    return (
        <Page>
            <Header headerWhite={currentRoute.headerWhite} />
            {props.children}
        </Page>
    )
}

App.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

Still, it solves my problem but I don't know it there is a better way to do it. So if somebody has a better solution, please give it and I'll accept your answer !